# Randomize between different intervals depending on conditions

Tags: c++, c++14

I'm trying do this code work

Basically what I want is to make a guessing game and according to the difficulty the code will choose a random number between a certain space.

```
char dificult;
    cin >> dificult;

    int attempts; 

    if(dificult== 'F'){
        attempts= 15;       
    }
    else if(dificult== 'M'){
        attempts= 10;
    }
    else{
        attempts= 5;
    }

const int SECRET_NUMBER;

if (dificult== 'Easy')
    {
       const int SECRET_NUMBER= rand() % 50;
       cout << "Your Number is in between 0 and 50." << endl;
       cout << "You Have 15 attempts" << endl;
    }
    else if(dificult== 'Medium'){
       const int SECRET_NUMBER= rand() % 100;
       cout << "Your Number is in between 0 and 100." << endl;
       cout << "You Have 10 attempts" << endl;
    }
    else{
       const int SECRET_NUMBER= rand() % 1000;
       cout << "Your Number is in between 0 and 1000." << endl;
       cout << "You Have 5 attempts" << endl;
    }'''
```

Answer (score 1):

`SECRET_NUMBER` in the global scope and the `SECRET_NUMBER`'s in the if branches are each different variables. Instead of defining new variables, just use the one you already have

```
int SECRET_NUMBER;

if (dificult== 'Easy')
{
   SECRET_NUMBER= rand() % 50;
   cout << "Your Number is in between 0 and 50." << endl;
   cout << "You Have 15 attempts" << endl;
}
else if(dificult== 'Medium'){
   SECRET_NUMBER= rand() % 100;
   cout << "Your Number is in between 0 and 100." << endl;
   cout << "You Have 10 attempts" << endl;
}
else{
   SECRET_NUMBER= rand() % 1000;
   cout << "Your Number is in between 0 and 1000." << endl;
   cout << "You Have 5 attempts" << endl;
}
```